# trouble with implementing classes

Tags: java

I have trouble implementing the classes for Car ship and plane. I already made an interface which is:

```
public interface Movable 
    public void moveForward();
    public void moveForward(int x);
    public void moveBackward();
    public void moveBackward(int x);
    public void moveLeft();
    public void moveLeft(int y);
    public void moveRight();
    public void moveRight(int y);
    public void displayCoordinates();
```

But i want to have two `int` fields to keep track of the coordinates (x, y).

•   The default coordinates will be (0, 0), and an overloaded constructor will allow the user to initialize them to other values.

•   The movement of the objects will change the coordinates (x, y) one step at a time by default depending on the direction (i.e. `moveForward()` will add `1` to `x`, `moveLeft()` will subtract `1` from `y`). Overloaded methods will allow the user to change the coordinates a n number of steps at a time (i.e. `moveForward( 7 )` will add `7` to `x`). But I don't know what do. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you restate your question to be more specific?

Comment: I nedd help implementing three classes, Car(), Plane(), and Ship(), I already create the classes, how do I use the "int" fields fields to keep track of the coordinates (x, y). How do I initialized the default coordinates to other values, and how do I move the coordinates forward,backward, left, and right?

Answer (score 3):

An interface defines methods that implementing classes need to implement. They do not define variables or maintain values for variables.

For example, you might have this:

```
public interface Movable {
    public void moveLeft(int x);
}
```

And then you would have a class that implements the interface:

```
public class Ball implements Movable {
    private int position;

    public Ball() {
        // Set the initial position
        position = 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveLeft(int x) {
        position = position - x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good book :)  Higher dimensions are left as an exercise for the person who asked the question.